# Is there a way to change a css file with clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a root css style file and I have defined some color variables in that. for ex:

```
--background-blue-primary: #005a9e;
```

Also, in my main html file there is a button to change theme. when someone clicked on that, i want the color code in variable to change.
how can i do that?

---

Comment: Define some classes(say classname1, classname2) in your root css file, then on button click event use yourelement.removeClass('classname1') and yourelement.AddClass('classname2') to change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
document.getElementById('themeChangeButton')
  .addEventListener('click', () => document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--background-blue-primary', '#ff4500'));
```

```css
:root {
  --background-blue-primary: #005a9e;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-blue-primary);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  This is some content to see the effect of theme change.
</div>

<button id="themeChangeButton">Change Theme</button>
```

or

```js
document.getElementById('themeChangeButton')
  .addEventListener('click', () => document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ff4500');
```

```css
:root {
  --background-blue-primary: #005a9e;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-blue-primary);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  This is some content to see the effect of theme change.
</div>

<button id="themeChangeButton">Change Theme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 variables as you want.

```
--background-blue-primary: #005a9e;
--background-green-primary: #008000;
```

On clicking a button, just add a custom class "green_theme" to the BODY tag or DIV using Javascript.

```
<script>
        // JavaScript to add class on button click
        document.getElementById('addClassButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.body.classList.add('green_theme');
        });
    </script>
```

If you use jQuery, use below code.

```
<script>
        // jQuery code to add class on button click
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addClassButton').click(function() {
                $('body').addClass('green_theme');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Write the CSS by targeting the 'green_theme' class.

```
.green_theme .button{background-color:var(--background-green-primary);}
```

Change the Classname (green_theme), Button ID (#addClassButton) and CSS Variables accordingly.